# Weird behavior, elements move when slider scrolls

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bxslider

Today i got the following site from another designer, he makes the frontend, and i add the functionality to all of the websites.

There is a weird issue going on and it's happening only in Google Chrome, i have tried a lot of things but i cannot find the cause of it.

The website is made using bootstrap 3

Here is the link to the site and the section that is being affected.

[Go to site](http://enobasistemas.com/serytelresponsive/index.php#sale)

What's happening is that when the slider with the images above moves an element (right now is [bxslider plugin](http://bxslider.com/) but it was before Bootstrap own slider, and even caroufredsel, same issue) the images on the container below, and others move a bit from side to side.

I have no idea what is causing it, I wonder if any of you guys can help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow i managed to track the issue, probably something related to the **bxslider**, (since it's the only control on which this is happening) so i'll answer here for future references and if someone else runs on the same thing.

What was causing the movement on the images below was the **boostrap** class `.block` when added the atribute `margin:0 auto;` or `text-align:center` to the images within the parent container inside block

Removed that and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `useCSS` to `false` to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the typical use of this setting and why it would resolve the OP's specific issue?

Comment: This doesn't even apply to the code, its not a valid answer, nor useful

Comment: This actually helped an issue I had where the slider went too far on the last slide.